# Print bytes in C, only non-printable characters as hex

Tags: c, arrays

I have a program creating some byte strings that are a mix of human-readable text and control bytes (including null bytes). In order to debug these strings I would like to have a function that prints these strings, given a pointer and a size, in a way that I can read the printable ASCII characters on screen, as well as the hex value of the non-printable ones (à la Python), e.g.

```
first string\x00second string\x00\x01
```

So far I have a function that only prints the printable characters:

```
void print_bytes(unsigned char *bs, size_t size) {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        fputc(bs[i], stdout);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Other than that, I have only seen examples online print everything as hex sequences, which does not help me understand the contents of the strings.

How can I improve the function above to print the hex values of non-printable characters?

Comment: If you understand the examples, what's stopping you from checking if the character is printable, outputting it if so and outputting it in hex if not?

Comment: `ctype.h` provides the `isprint()` macro that can simplify your `if (isprint (c)) { /* print it */ } else { /* output hex */ }`

Comment: David, Thanks. That is the type of function that I was looking for.

Comment: Please make this an answer and mark it. It helps others finding the solution which will otherweise be hidden in the comments and the question will still be listed as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the suggestion in the comment, I rewrote the function to use the `isprint` swicth:

```
void print_bytes(const unsigned char *bs, const size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if isprint(bs[i]) {
            fputc(bs[i], stdout);
        } else {
            printf("\\x%02x", bs[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```